# How do I extract a column's TEXT values, which are JSON lists, into a virtual table?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table with a schema like this:

```
-- user table

| id | postIds |
|----|---------|
|  1 | [1,2,3] |
|  2 | [4,5,6] |
```

`postIds` is a `TEXT` column with `TEXT` values. How can I implement a query that returns all `postId`s as rows in a (virtual) table?

```
-- Get postIds from all rows in user table. Desired result:

| postId |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      5 |
|      6 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Sqlite was built with the [JSON1 extension](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) enabled, it's easy:

```
sqlite> SELECT j.value AS postID FROM user JOIN json_each(user.postIds) AS j ORDER BY j.value;
postID
----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
```